# What is that neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am teaching my comp to add naturals by creating a neural network:

```
trainingset = {"1+2" -> 3, "2+2" -> 4, "3+9" -> 12, "4+5" -> 9, 
"6+2" -> 8, "5+4" -> 9, "1+8" -> 9, "2+8" -> 10}; 
p = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
p["3+4"] // Round
```

> `8`

Not so bad, taking into account a small size of the `trainingset`.

What neural network is created by `p`? What layers does the one include? I  find an answer in neither

```
Information[p, "Properties"]
```

> {"AcceptanceThreshold", "AnomalyDetector", "BatchEvaluationSpeed", 
> "BatchEvaluationTime", "Calibrated", "EvaluationTime", 
> "ExampleNumber", "FeatureExtractor", "FeatureNames", "FeatureNumber", 
> "FeatureTypes", "FunctionMemory", "FunctionProperties", 
> "IndeterminateThreshold", "LearningCurve", "MaxTrainingMemory", 
> "MeanCrossEntropy", "Method", "MethodDescription", "MethodOption", 
> "MethodParameters", "MissingSynthesizer", "PerformanceGoal", 
> "Properties", "StandardDeviation", "TrainingLabelMean", 
> "TrainingTime", "UtilityFunction"}

nor

```
Information[p, "MethodDescription"]
```

> "An neural networks is composed of layers of artificial neuron units. Each unit computes its value as a
> function of the unit values in the previous layer. Information is processed layer by layer from the feature layer
> to the \noutput unit which gives the predicted value. It is also called a feed-forward neural network or a
> multi-layer perceptron"

Is that neural network similar to In[22] in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html?fbclid=IwAR19SWn_mF0KsxBRBd4vLfr8gMgxSH9p6SQ_i4Qe-Oq09T-Q11HpxcOqM6Q#1013067167)?

Comment: The network itself can be extracted by `p[[1]]["Model"]["Network"]`, and you can generally dive into the predictor function by replacing its head with `List`, e.g. `List@@p`. However, there is some preprocessing involved in formatting the input to the network, and the network itself is a bit on the complicated side to dive into.

Comment: @eyorble: Thank you. The result of `p[[1]]["Model"]["Network"]` is not clear to me. Can you kindly give an answer, elaborating your comment?